# 406 (Not Acceptable) in spring mvc error

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

If my spring-servlet.xml is

```
<bean id="defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />


 <bean id="annotationMethodHandlerAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
                    <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
                </list>
            </property>

        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

everything is fine.
But the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter is not adviced.So I change the xml like this

```
<bean id="defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" />
    <bean id="annotationMethodHandlerAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter" />

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
                    <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
                </list>
            </property>

        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

then there is a mistake **406 (Not Acceptable)**

The backstage is good,no error.
Then I delete the

```
<bean id="defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" />
    <bean id="annotationMethodHandlerAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter" />
```

everything is good now.
So I want ask If I delete the code is right or wrong?
If it is wrong! How can I fix it?
Thank you,I am looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Delete it... Those are already registered through `<mvc:annotation-driven />` it adds nothing but a badly configured instance.